# Flask refuses to load server in vscode debug

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I can't get flask to run with a mini project and default settings in vscode and using a conda environment with only flask installed. No matter what I try the flask run will startup with. the going to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ will give below error message. It doesn't matter if I run from prompt. Run as debug or any other flask -m run etc.

CODE:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"


flask run
     * Serving Flask app "app.py"
     * Environment: production
       WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
       Use a production WSGI server instead.
     * Debug mode: off
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

{
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
```

Error message

```
File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\sgpython\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 330, in __call__
rv = self._load_unlocked()
File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\sgpython\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\sgpython\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 372, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\sgpython\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 246, in locate_app
'Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name)
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "server".
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some packages. Try to run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed` and see if that works.

Also - make sure your launch config `FLASK_APP` entry is set to the directory your app is being run.

The location of your Python interpreter must be included in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I have now managed to get it to run. But still can't get it to stop on a breakpoint.